# Creating generic method for dynamic hyperlinks in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, gridview

I am binding gridview with dynamic links in RowDataBound gridview event and it works perfectly. Since I need to generate hyperlinks for lot of columns, is there any way to create a generic method which could return hyperlink objects.

**Code:**

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                string strHeaderRow = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;

                if (strHeaderRow == "EmployeeID")
                {
                    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
                    string strURL = "EmpURL";
                    hl.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                    hl.Font.Underline = true;
                    hl.Target = "_blank";
                    hl.NavigateUrl = strURL;
                    hl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hl);
                }
                else if (strHeaderRow == "Department")
                {
                    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
                    string strURL = "DepURL";
                    hl.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                    hl.Font.Underline = true;
                    hl.Target = "_blank";
                    hl.NavigateUrl = strURL;
                    hl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 1:**

```
  public HyperLink hlCol(string strURL)
    {
        HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
        string strURL = "DepURL";
        hl.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
        hl.Font.Underline = true;
        hl.Target = "_blank";
        hl.NavigateUrl = strURL;
        hl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
        e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hl);
        return hl;
    }
```

I'm able to write a method but how can I add handle the below statement which requires an index and GridViewRowEventArgs.

```
 hl.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
 e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hl);
```

Comment: why generic? make a normal method that returns a `HyperLink` object and receives all the necessary parameters.

Comment: actually the code you posted differs only in the `NavigateUrl` assignment, so you would actually need 2 parameters for the method: the  `Text` and the `NavigateUrl` part. the rest can be set hard in the method, but it would make it more flexible if you pass all the necessary parameters

Comment: @MongZhu- Updated my post. Please take a look.

Comment: no need for the index, simply pass the `string` that is in `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` as a second parameter into the `hlCol` method :), you can also remove the `string strURL = "DepURL";` since this information should be in the parameter variable `string strURL`. also the adding to the controls needs to go, because you will use this line `e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hl);` outside of this method when you get the retuned `HyperLink` object from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a generic method, maybe you used generic as in "in a generic way"

You could try the following:

```
protected void AddHyperLink(TableCell cell, string strURL)
{
    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
    hl.Text = cell.Text;
    hl.Font.Underline = true;
    hl.Target = "_blank";
    hl.NavigateUrl = strURL;
    hl.Attributes.Add("style", "color:Black;");
    cell.Controls.Add(hl);
}

protected void AddAllLinks(GridView gridView, GridViewRowEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, string> urls)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            var key = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
            string url;
            if (urls.TryGetValue(key, out url))
            {
                AddHyperLink(e.Row.Cells[i], url);
            }
        }
    }
}
static readonly Dictionary<string, string> headersToUrls = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {  "Department", "DepUrl" },
    { "EmployeeID", "EmpURL" }
};
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    AddAllLinks(GridView1, e, headersToUrls);
}
```

The logic to create a hyperlink is in `AddHyperLink` which takes the url to redirect to. The `AddAllLinks` will create links for all columns for which a header text is defined in the dictionary passed as a parameter. The original handler just invokes the `AddAllLinks` with a dictionary that specifies a dictionary wihc contains the header to url mappings

If you need the link to be customizable by row, you could either use a string template which you pass to `string.Format` when you create the url, or you could use a `Dictionary<string, Func<TableCell, string>>` which would allow you to specify custom code to be executed when constructing the link.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Wops,. forgot to change it, it was to be instead on the hard coded url